# delphi fdquery mysql insert in a loop

Tags: delphi

i have to insert in a loop.
in my while to read from other database i get data and create my insert query like this

```
 form2.FDQuery4.First;
 while (not form2.FDQuery4.Eof) do begin
   try
     form2.FDQuery5.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO `tm_frame_data_val` (`frame_data_id`, `value`, `act_date`) VALUES ( :fdida, :value, :acdoo );';
     form2.FDQuery5.Command.CommandKind := skInsert;

          form2.FDQuery5.ParamByName('fdida').Value := '1';     //form2.FDQuery4.FieldByName('tfdid').AsString
          form2.FDQuery5.ParamByName('value').Value := '1';    // TmFielsDataVal
          form2.FDQuery5.ParamByName('acdoo').Value := '1';  //tmSentTimeStamp.ToString

     form2.FDQuery5.Execute;

   finally
     form2.ListBox3.Items.Add( 'error on writing to db' );
   end;
  form2.FDQuery4.Next;
 end;
```

in my loop i got this error

[image]

i used `Execute` or `OpenOrExecute` or `ExecSQL` buy get this error all time.
why this happens in a insert query !?

also when i used `try` ,`finally` why it show error in `showmessage` !?

Comment: You need to add an MCVE to your q.  Btw, your `finally` should be an `except`.  `finally` always executes.  Also, you could change your query to select * from tm_frame_data_val, then just call FDQuery5.Open and call Insert ...Post on it.

Comment: @MartynA thank you for `Except` but i dont underestant your comment about `open` , i have a insert query.i dont need open any dataset..

Comment: Well, if you call Open, then you can use the dataset's Insert method to insert a row.  You don't need to construct a Sql INSERT statement yourself, at all.  Btw, have you looked at FireDAC's BatchMove components?

Comment: @MartynA the wired thing is when i comment code in the `try - finally` the error dont appear and Of course dont store records in database .so it seems the error related this part of code. can this be caused due to a bug when i insert in loop fastly ?!

Comment: after a lot of tests and researches i completed my project with `unidac` component with a same code style.so it seems this is a bug in firedac that i will submit in embarcadero quality center ASAP

Answer (score 0):

Try one or both of the following:

1)  Assign CommandKind := skInsert before ExecSQL:

```
form2.FDQuery5.Command.CommandKind := skInsert;
form2.FDQuery5.ExecSQL;
```

2)  Use OpenOrExecute instead of ExecSQL:

```
form2.FDQuery5.OpenOrExecute;
```

These are untested by me, but the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/TFDQuery,_TFDStoredProc_and_TFDUpdateSQL_Questions) (see "Q3") seems to indicate this would be your solution.